# PHP regex expression to find if a string contains YYYY-MM-DD

Tags: php, regex, string, date

I would like to check if a URL (or any string) contains any form of the following pattern ####-##-##

Does anyone have a handy str_replace() or regular expression to do that?

something like:

```
contains_date_string($string);
```

returns true if $string contains ####-##-##

Thank you!!!

Comment: What did you try? Also: Google has many results for date regexps.

Comment: I have no idea how to use regex.

Comment: So now is a *perfect* time to learn how.

Comment: That would make my life so much better!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (preg_match('/\b\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\b/', $str)) {
    // ...
}
```

If the word boundary (`\b`) doesn't do the trick, you could try [negative lookbehind and lookaheads](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
if (preg_match('/(?<!\d)\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}(?!\d)/', $str)) {
    // ...
}
```

As an additional validation, you could use [`checkdate()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php) to weed out invalid dates such as `9999-02-31` as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10476175/166339).

Answer (score 3):

Use `preg_match` in conjunction with `checkdate`:

```
function contains_date($str)
{
    if (preg_match('/\b(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})\b/', $str, $matches))
    {
        if (checkdate($matches[2], $matches[3], $matches[1]))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Interesting solution Kep! Thank you. Is using checkdate more efficient than the answer I posted below?

Comment: This will return true for input like this: `"This is not 1239202-02-120331231 valid"`.

Comment: Your solution allows xxxx-02-31 (Feb. 31st), which isn't a valid date.

Comment: @Asaph: Aye, missed that - fix incoming.

Answer (score 0):

```
'/^[0-9]{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])$/'
```

'Makes sure things like 1998-13-32 won't get past and validate.'

I got this from google... http://www.devnetwork.net/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=13795

Looks promising. Hope this will help someone on the search for the same as stackoverflow is **the** most accessible SEO wise.

Comment: The beginning and end anchors (`^` and `$`) will prevent the "contains" operation that the OP is asking about from working.

Answer (score 0):

The test given [here](http://html5pattern.com/) should work:

```
if (preg_match('#[0-9]{4}-(0[1-9]|1[012])-(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[01])#', $str)) {
   // do something
}
```

Whatever regex you choose, be careful! When a machine sees 2004-04-01, it won't be able to distinguish between January 4th and April Fools day unless you tell it otherwise...

Comment: This will return true for input like `"This is not 99991999-12-01213213 valid"`.